# updating field in user model whenever it used

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have extended user model in my project and need to update its field (last online) whenever user has authenticated. I use DRF and `IsAuthenticated` in permission classes, what is the best way to trigger update event?

Comment: I would create a middleware doing this

Comment: Are you using the `TokenAuthentication` provided by DRF or have you written something of your own?

Comment: `last online` - what does it mean in the context of (rest) api calls? Each GET? Are you sure you want it?

Comment: @IvanStarostin, not only `GET`. Yes, I'm sure

Comment: @SaadullahAleem, yes

Comment: In that case you could overwrite the default authorization middleware of and update the last_login field of the user but this could result in a lot of db calls.